# What is the unit of Margin in Advanced SubStation Alpha (ASS) subtitles file format?

Tags: subtitles, file-format

I can't find a good documentation for the Advanced SubStation Alpha (ASS) subtitles file format on internet and I am wondering, what is the unit of margin?

My intuition tells me it's a percentage but I'd like to be sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the specification](http://moodub.free.fr/video/ass-specs.doc) linked from [Matroska website](https://matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/ssa.html), it's in pixels as measured in the *subtitle author's screen resolution* (so it's scaled up or down by the player).

First in the website:

> The first, "[Script Info]" contains some information about the subtitle file, such as it's title, who created it, type of script and a very important one : "PlayResY". Be carefull of this value, everything in your script (font size, positioning) is scaled by it.

Then in the spec itself:

> Field 14: MarginL. This defines the Left Margin in pixels. It is the distance from the left-hand edge of the screen. The three onscreen margins (MarginL, MarginR, MarginV) define areas in which the subtitle text will be displayed.
>
> Field 15: MarginR. This defines the Right Margin in pixels. It is the distance from the right-hand edge of the screen. The three onscreen margins (MarginL, MarginR, MarginV) define areas in which the subtitle text will be displayed.
>
> Field 16: MarginV. This defines the vertical Left Margin in pixels.
> For a subtitle, it is the distance from the bottom of the screen.
> For a toptitle, it is the distance from the top of the screen.
> For a midtitle, the value is ignored - the text will be vertically centred.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is PlayResY a value in pixel? I think I may bee confused because of the strange value put by default when converting *srt* in *ass* with ffmpeg (`PlayResX: 384`, `PlayResY: 288`...)

Comment: Yes, the editing tools use the screen resolution in pixels. But for automated conversion it would certainly make sense to fill in the video's native resolution there instead, because the converter doesn't need the fine adjustment.

Comment: Alright, thank you

Comment: Links both fail